# Can CCK take care of my fields for a programatically defined node type in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

Does the CCK api allow me to create a node type, from a custom module, with a bunch of fields that use CCK to store their state?  If so can these fields be locked so that users may not alter them, but still allow the user to add more fields to the node type?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the answer to your first question is "yes" (for Drupal 6, at least, which has elements of the CCK integrated into Drupal Core).  I believe the [Amazon module](http://drupal.org/project/amazon) does this sort of thing, albeit it with just one field.

I don't think the idea in your second request is achievable, though.  This would seem to require field-level permissions' control whilst Drupal only supports module-level permissions' control.

Answer (score 0):

You could add validation code in the GUI which restricts CCK fields being interfered with on your content type. This would not prevent another module getting in there with an axe, though.

You could add checks which restore your preferred CCK settings whenever they detect some unwanted changes.